# Symfony 3 FOSUserBundle Prod Ajax calls return login form

Tags: php, ajax, symfony

I believe the solution to this question is rather obvious but I could not find it((.

I made an app in Symfony 3 with FOSUserBundle which uses ajax calls to my ajax controller to retrieve some data. In dev environment everything worked fine but when I deployed the app to prod all ajax calls started to return a login form instead of actual data. Although I am logged in and have access to all secured areas.  All caches have been cleared and assets installed. 
Any Ideas how to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: Maybe a silly question but do you just have security.yml or do you have a security_dev.yml and security_prod.yml ?

Answer (score 0):

Got the issue solved, the requests were headed to app_dev.php instead of app.php [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128710/ajax-request-in-prod-environment-causes-access-is-denied-user-in-not-fully-auth) helped